# UIActivityIndicator usage on this method - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to use UIActivityIndicator before my method works. The problem is my service calling method returns a value which prevents me to call

```
self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> method.
```

I used to call non returning methods with activity indicator without any problem.

But now i am not able to do it,

I hope i am clear enough to tell the issue.

Could you please help me?

My code is as follows;

```
-(InstrumentObject*)callInstrumentService:(NSString*)instrumentCode
{
    [Utils startActivityIndicator];

    InstrumentObject * instrumentObject;

    AppDelegate *appDel = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    GetInstrumentRequest * getInstrumentRequest = [[GetInstrumentRequest alloc]init];

    getInstrumentResponse = [[GetInstrumentResponse alloc]initWithDict:[appDel.serviceHelper serviceCall:[getInstrumentRequest createRequest:instrumentCode] withURL:appDel.appPage.businessServiceUrl withIdentifier:@"file"]];

    if(getInstrumentResponse.instrumentObject !=nil && getInstrumentResponse.instrumentObject.values.count !=0)
    {
        instrumentObject = getInstrumentResponse.instrumentObject;
    }

    [Utils stopActivityIndicator];

    return instrumentObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with UI in main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 [Utils startActivityIndicator];      
});

.......

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 [Utils stopActivityIndicator];   
});
```